# Flutter: How do I make an image overlay?

Tags: flutter

Is there any way for me to overlay images(wherein you use a background image and you put another image in front of it) in flutter?. Ive tried doing it in columns inside of a container, but it doesnt seem to be working. Any advices or tips? I appreciate all the help :)

Comment: you can use Stack widget bro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out below **example** for more idea:-

```
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    Container(
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
      color: Colors.red, // replace it with image
    ),
    Container(
      width: 90,
      height: 90,
      color: Colors.green,// replace it with image
    ),
    Container(
      width: 80,
      height: 80,
      color: Colors.blue, // replace it with image
    ),
  ],
)
```